# Adding the array totals from two separate quarters in java

Tags: java

I am working on a project to allow users to input values for two separate teams for a two-quarter game. The project should ask users to select which team scored and then how many points they got. Then,  it would total the points for each of the individual teams for the quarter. Finally, it should add each team's points for the two quarters together. Currently, I'm able to get the individual teams score for each quarter but, I am not sure how to add the points for each quarter together.

```
public class goingUp {
static int team1[] = new int[4];
static int team2[] = new int[4];
static int teamOneScore = 0;
static int teamTwoScore = 0;            
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) { for (int Quarter = 1; Quarter <= 2; Quarter++) {
        System.out.println("Quarter " + Quarter +"\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("What team scored?(1 or 2)");
            int iTeam = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("How many points did they score (1,2, or 3)");
            int pointsScored = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (iTeam == 1) {
                teamOneScore += pointsScored;
            } else if (iTeam == 2) {
                teamTwoScore += pointsScored;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Team 1 score is " + teamOneScore);
        System.out.println("Team 2 score is " + teamTwoScore);

        for (int i = 0; i < team1.length; i++) {

            team1 = new int[]{teamOneScore};
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Team one score for all Quarters is " + teamTotal(team1));
}

static int teamTotal(int team[]){

    int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
            sum += team[i];
        }
        return sum;
}
```

}

Comment: "*I am not sure how to add the points for each quarter together*" `+` operator?

Comment: Your players are using coins? Could you explain more deeply, please.

Comment: @NomadMaker    No, there are two quarters that each team has to score, and I'm trying to get each team total score. So for team one, if they got a score of 15 for the first quarter and 3 for the second I'm trying to figure out how to get and add that 15 + 3 for the total game score.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over both arrays and sum the corresponding elements:

```java
int[] bothTeamsScore = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    bothTeamsScore[i] = teamOneScore[i] + teamTwoScore[i];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment below, I misunderstood the question. To sum each team's score, you could iterate over the array and sum it

```
private static long sum(int[] scores) {
    long sum = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; ++i) {
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

long teamOneTotal = sum(teamOneScore);
long teamTwoTotal = sum(teamTwoScore);
```

Alternatively, streams can make this method a tad simpler:

```
private static long sum(int[] scores) {
    return Arrays.stream(scores).sum();
}
```

Comment: I not trying to add together the two separate team scores. What im trying to do what get the total separate score for each team. So each team has two quarters to score points. Team one may get 10pts the first Quarter and 8 the second. What I would need to do is figure out how to get and then add 10, 8 for the final team one score

Comment: @boldercoder I misunderstood the question then. See my edited answer.